# Update detail "content status" of MS Word documents with Perl / Batch / Python

Tags: python, perl, batch-file, ms-word

I am currently trying to modify the field "Content Status" that appears in the Windows Explorer in the "Details" section of a MS Word .docx file properties (i.e. *Right-Click on file from Windows Explorer* > *Properties* > *Details*) as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Right Click > Properties > Details]

Does anyone know how to change the value of "Content status" with a Perl script (or eventually batch script or python)?

I am familiar with Win32:OLE to modify Excel and Word documents but don't know how to approach the problem.

Thanks

Comment: One of these may help you http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=570319 or  http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.perl.misc/how-read-ms-word-summary-properties/477092

Comment: @harvey: Thanks for the link! It is indeed changing the properties but I was looking to some other properties that cannot be modified from MS Word. Answer of Haf below pointed me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to 'Haf Linger', I managed to found the answer to my problem:

```
#!perl

use strict;
use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS );

##CONFIG##
my $new_status="Closed";
my $docx_name="TEST.docx";
my $tmp_name="tmp.docx";
my $replace_file=1; #set to 0 for testing purpose
####

#Open docx file
my $doc = Archive::Zip->new($docx_name);

#Retrieve old status
my $old_status=undef;
my $new_content=$doc->contents('docProps/core.xml');
if ($new_content=~s%<cp:contentStatus>\s*(.*?)\s*</cp:contentStatus>%%) {
    $old_status=$1;
} else {}

#Update with new status
printf "Update status of $docx_name to '$new_status'%s: ",
    (defined $old_status ? " (previously '$old_status')" : "");
$new_content=~s%(</cp:coreProperties>)%<cp:contentStatus>$new_status</cp:contentStatus>$1%;
my ($content, $status) = $doc->contents('docProps/core.xml',$new_content);
if ($status) { 
    print "error during update of status of $docx_name ($!)\n"; 
} else {
    print "done!\n";
}

#Save file to temporary file
unless ( $doc->writeToFileNamed($tmp_name) == AZ_OK ) {
       die 'write error';
   }

#Replace if needed
if ($replace_file) {
    use File::Copy;
    move($tmp_name, $docx_name);
} else {}
```

Answer (score 1):

property `<cp:contentStatus>` can be found in the `docProps/core.xml` file.
Changing the content of this xml element will update the field you were referring to. (assuming you are talking docx files here)

Using `Archive::Zip` you will be able to open up the docx file and access the core.xml file and change its content and zip things back into an updated docx file.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Helped me to find the right solution.